# UI: "Page 1 of 0" OR "Page 1 of 1" OR "Page 0 of 0" for ZERO rows?

Tags: user-interface

In an empty dataset, what is more correct to put in the pagination information in the screen?

- Page 1 of 0
- Page 1 of 1
- Page 0 of 0

Answer (score 11):

"Page 1 of 1"

You are still printing a page out, even if it is to say "There is no data available for your query".

Answer (score 10):

**"No results found"** and not showing a malformed dataset at all would be my UE method of choice, 95% of the time.

0 of 0 if you must though, anything else implies some data exists.

Comment: +1. Don't print a page, you clown. What have the trees ever done to you? :-)

Comment: The media isn't paper... it is screen!

Comment: I think he was being facetious :) Showing tables (or whatever) with all the attendant headers, footers and nav controls with no data to relate to is a design anti-pattern. You should present the information at hand in as clear and concise a way as possible.

Comment: I should say my "0/0" view is web-centric, JeeBee may be thinking from a more traditional standpoint.

Answer (score 9):

Or you just don’t print the pagination if there is no dataset.

Comment: Yes, who needs clutter? Treat it like a different screen than one that shows data, if it makes you feel better.

Answer (score 1):

Its gotta be Page 1 of 1 if a page exists at all. IMO there should not be any pages for empty datasets.